# Need to assign the correct value to each transaction based on a separate table

Tags: python, pandas

I need to assign the correct fiscal period to each transaction based on a separate table.

I have two datasets.

Dataset 1 has transaction information as below:

| Transaction Number | Transaction Date | Customer Name | Fiscal Period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 01-JAN-2022 | ABC Company |  |
| 123500 | 03-MAR-2022 | Z Company |  |
| 124600 | 01-APR-2022 | X Company |  |
| 124700 | 04-FEB-2022 | XYZ Company |  |

Dataset 2 is the table listing the fiscal periods for each start/end date.

| Start Date | End Date | Fiscal Period |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-JAN-2022 | 04-FEB-2022 | JAN-2022 |
| 05-FEB-2022 | 04-MAR-2022 | FEB-2022 |
| 05-MAR-2022 | 01-APR-2022 | MAR-2022 |

Expected result:

| Transaction Number | Transaction Date | Customer Name | Fiscal Period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 01-JAN-2022 | ABC Company | JAN-2022 |
| 123500 | 03-MAR-2022 | Z Company | FEB-2022 |
| 124600 | 01-APR-2022 | X Company | MAR-2022 |
| 124700 | 04-FEB-2022 | XYZ Company | JAN-2022 |

Could someone please help me with how I could accomplish this using Python/Pandas? The only way I know how to handle something similar is by using the pd.merge function. However, since the "key" value is a range (start/end dates), I have no clue on how to go about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This does the job,

```
df1["Transaction Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Transaction Date"])
df2 = df2.apply(pd.to_datetime)

transaction_date = df1.loc[1, "Transaction Date"]
fiscal_periods_indices = []

for transaction_date in df1["Transaction Date"]:
  fiscal_period = df2[(transaction_date >= df2["Start Date"]) & (transaction_date <= df2["End Date"])].index[0]
  fiscal_periods_indices.append(fiscal_period)

df1["Fiscal Period"] = df2.loc[fiscal_periods_indices, "Fiscal Period"].reset_index(drop = True)
```

Output -

|  | Transaction Number | Transaction Date | Customer Name | Fiscal Period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 123456 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | ABC Company | 2022-01-01 |
| 1 | 123500 | 2022-03-03 00:00:00 | Z Company | 2022-02-01 |
| 2 | 124600 | 2022-04-01 00:00:00 | X Company | 2022-03-01 |
| 3 | 124700 | 2022-02-04 00:00:00 | XYZ Company | 2022-01-01 |

Answer (score 0):

Since your intervals do not overlap, you can use `pd.cut`:

```
bins = pd.to_datetime(df2['Start Date'].to_list() + [df2['End Date'].iloc[-1]])

df1['Fiscal Period'] = pd.cut(pd.to_datetime(df1['Transaction Date']), bins=bins,
                              labels=df2['Fiscal Period'], include_lowest=True)
```

Output:

| Transaction Number | Transaction Date | Customer Name | Fiscal Period |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 01-JAN-2022 | ABC Company | JAN-2022 |
| 123500 | 03-MAR-2022 | Z Company | FEB-2022 |
| 124600 | 01-APR-2022 | X Company | MAR-2022 |
| 124700 | 04-FEB-2022 | XYZ Company | JAN-2022 |